# reiniciar conteo de cuenta atrás

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un código Javascript que después de una cuenta atrás muestra el contenido de un div. Me gustaría aplicar una regla al código para que si se cambia de pestaña del navegador pero no se cierra la página, cuando vuelva a esta pestaña se reinicie el conteo.

No consigo hacerlo, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

```js
var segundos = 72;
var progress = setInterval(function(){
segundos--;
if(segundos > 0){
$('#contador').text('El Codigo se mostrará en '+segundos+' segundos!');
} else if(segundos == 0){
clearInterval(progress);
$('#contador').hide();
$('#contenido').fadeIn();
}
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Juan. Dices que no consigues hacerlo pero en tu codigo no veo ningun intento a lo que pides. Puedes editar la pregunta para añadir lo que has probado y tus errores concretos? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info.

Comment: Si aparte de lo que dice @lois6b añades el **HTML** podremos reproducir el caso correctamente y será más sencillo el ayudarte.

Comment: He editado el código para hacerlo funcional

Comment: lo que intentado, es una cosa que he encontrado por internet pero lo único que hace es que la función no se ejecuta al iniciar el documento sino al cargar el body. como no me servia por eso lo he quitado. Disculpad soy nuevo en el foro y no sabia que se podían hacer códigos ejecutables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes más que *escuchar* el evento `"focus"`. Ya que estás usando jQuery, el código quedaría así:

```js
var segundos = 72;
var progress = setInterval(function() {
  segundos--;
  if(segundos > 0){
    $('#contador').text('El Codigo se mostrará en '+segundos+' segundos!');
  } else if(segundos == 0){
    clearInterval(progress);
    $('#contador').hide();
    $('#contenido').fadeIn();
  }
}, 1000);

$(window).focus(function() {
  segundos = 72;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contador"></div>
```

Usando puro Javascript sería

```
window.addEventListener('focus',function () {
  segundos = 72;
)
```

Comment: muchas gracias pablo, pero lo he provado y si cambio de pestaña y vuelvo a la pagina la cuenta sigue.. no vuelve a reiniciarse ..

Comment: ¿Lo has probado en tu página o aquí? Te lo comento porque el código ejecutable de StackOverflow está en un iframe, con lo que sólo gana el *focus* cuando haces click sobre esa parte de la página.

Comment: lo he provado en mi pagina

Comment: Curioso, me funciona aquí si le doy a ejecutar y doy el foco al iframe: cambio entre pestañas y lo veo reiniciando la cuenta